# Prevent Submit for Translation for different version of languages

Tags: lightning-knowledge

I have a requirement where I need to prevent Submit for Translation for different version of languages, for example, if the knowledge article is in English and I need to prevent Submit for Translation for English (UK). I created a trigger for the Knowledge object and it is preventing the creation but it's always showing "Something went wrong"

In the trigger for testing I'm just using addError for every record:

```
trigger KnowledgeArticleTrigger on Support_Site__kav (before insert) {
    for (Support_Site__kav ka : Trigger.new) {
       ka.addError('***** ERROR *****');
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see

'***** ERROR *****'
but always see

Something went wrong.

[image]

Any ideas of how to display a specific error? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try adding a if statement checking if the article language is correct and throw a custom exception .

Comment: Hi @SubratSrivastava, yes, I tried throwing a custom exception and I'm seeing same behavior.